# How to retrieve array of single key-value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of javascript objects and i need to return just the id and the corresponding value to end with an array that looks something like:

`[{"id":"groupID123"}, {"id":"groupID321"}]`

so that I can submit it to an API.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map it:

```js
var array=[{"id":"groupID123", "someKey":'Key1'}, {"id":"groupID321", 'someKey':'Key2'}];
var result1 = array.map(({id})=>id);
console.log(result1);

// OR 

var result2 = array.map(({id})=>({id}));
console.log(result2);
```